# How to show columns which are not part of $group clause in aggregate query

Tags: mongodb

I would like to output result of my $unwind operation into another collection and getting duplicate _id error.  In order to overcome it I am using $group to produce a new _id field.  How can I project extra fields from collection?  When I am using $project clause it doesn't output anything.

This one works:

```
db.audit.aggregate([
{$match: { "date": { $gte : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                     $lt : ISODate("2015-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            },
{ $unwind : "$data.items" } ,

{ $group : {
    "_id" : {
         "_id":"$_id",
         "sku":"$data.items.sku"
            }
    } 
},
{ 
    $out : "randomAggregates"
}
]
)
```

This one doesn't:

```
db.audit.aggregate([
{$match: { "date": { $gte : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                     $lt : ISODate("2015-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            },
{ $unwind : "$data.items" } ,
{ $project: { "ccy" : "$data.crncy",  
              "coo" : "$data.items.coo",
              "order_id" : "$meta.refid"
            }
},
{ $group : {
    "_id" : {
         "_id":"$_id",
         "sku":"$data.items.sku"
            }
    } 
},
{ 
    $out : "randomAggregates"
}
]
)
```

Thank you

Comment: "works / doesn't work" are you getting an exception? error? some more info might help.

Comment: empty collection got produced

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**$first**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator in the `$group` stage and access the whole document using the [**$$ROOT**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable.

```
{$group:{"_id":{"_id":"$_id","sku":"$data.items.sku"},
         "value":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}}
```

or,

```
   {$group:{"_id":{"_id":"$_id","sku":"$data.items.sku"},
             "field":{$first:"$field"}}}  // do this for all the fields.
```

Your modified code would look like:

```
db.audit.aggregate([
{$match: { "date": { $gte : ISODate("2015-01-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
                     $lt : ISODate("2015-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            },
{ $unwind : "$data.items" } ,
{$group:{"_id":{"_id":"$_id","sku":"$data.items.sku"},
         "value":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}}   // you could do it for individual 
                                       // fields as well here
{ 
    $out : "randomAggregates"
}
]
)
```